# Optimizing function to modify member variables in different classes

Tags: c#

I have 2 classes that have exact two functions. The difference between them is they modify the member variables of their own class.

```
class A
{ 
     public hello;

     public void methodA ()
     {
         // code to modify hello
     }
}
class B
{ 
     public hello;

     public void methodB()
     {
          // code to modify hello
     }
}
```

Method A and B do the exact same thing but to different hello (one in class A one in class B).
Is there any way I can avoid duplication here? I think probably delegate will be the answer, but I don't know how. Please give me guidelines, I am a student and still learning. Thanks beforehand.

EDIT: The reason the classes have the same functionality but are separate classes, is because one is in a Windows application, and the other in a console application.

Comment: could A and B possibly have some inheritance relationship?

Comment: My application can run as windows app and console app. One is for windows app, one is for console app. And no, they dont have inheritance relationship.

Comment: there's no reason a windows app and a console app can't share common functionality. move this logic into one class, into it's own assembly, and reference that assembly from both your windows app and console app

Comment: @ErOx hey I followed your instruction. I did not realize that windows app and console app can share common functionality. Thanks!! You may want to make your comment as an answer to my question so I can mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the classes share the exact same functionality, then they should be combined into one class. If you have to share this class among different applications, you can put this class into a separate assembly, and reference the assembly from both your Windows and console applications.